# Rails route with dynamic segments not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following non-resourceful route with dynamic segments:

```
get 'places/near/:lat/:lng' => 'places#near', as: 'near_places'
```

When I run 'rake routes', the route is there:

```
near_places GET    /places/near/:lat/:lng(.:format)    places#near
```

But, when I try to use the path in the view like this:

```
near_places_path( lat: place.lat, lng: place.lng )
```

I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"places", :action=>"near"}
```

No matter how I twist it :)

Rails v. 3.2.11

Thanks for any ideas...

Comment: Are you sure that the errors is raised because of the line you mentioned? Please make sure that you're not using that url helper in another place (probably with no arguments at all).

Comment: What are you passing in? It might be breaking your routes.

Comment: As always.. stupid mistake :) I had the path used in the form on other place (so there were no parameters). Thanks @AhmadSherif for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to point keys for this route, just use appropriate values in declared order.

I.e. `near_places_path( place.lat, place.lng )`